# R: How can I solve the Error Code for apply function for multiple variables?

Tags: r

I have two data frames for the firms X and Y, each containing dates and daily returns, similar to this:

```
firm.data 
X  Date         Return      
2019-01-25      0.007523323
2019-01-28     -0.004778901
2019-01-29      0.004801849

Y  Date         Return      
2019-01-25      0.019767443
2019-01-28     -0.001900380
2019-01-29     -0.006473724
```

I put both in a list called "firm.data" and for each firm I want to add a new column called "AR" respectively (I am working with lists because I will add more firm data frames in the future and I don't want to do all calculations separately). The new column "AR" should include data calculated with an anonymous function "ar_calc" containing the calculations for a CAPM model [firm return - (alpha + (beta * market return))]. I have already calculated the respective alphas and betas for both X and Y and stored them in two lists called "alphas" and "betas".

```
alphas = c(0.0028, -0.0010)
betas = c(1.7099, 0.9242)
```

I also have the data frame mkt.data:

```
mkt.data   
Date          Return  
2019-01-25    0.013621555
2019-01-28   -0.006335916
2019-01-29    0.000760060
```

To add the new column to each data frame, I have been trying to use the apply function combined with the anonymous function (see code below).

However, this always returns the following error:

> Error in is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) : Argument ".data" is missing without default

Since I am quite new to R, I hope this explanation makes sense. I would appreciate any help with this!

I have already tried different functions (lapply and mapply) but do not know how to calculate the new column with three variables (firm data for X and Y, alphas for X and Y and betas for X and Y) in the function called "ar_calc".

My code currently looks like this:

```
ar_calc <- function (x, y, z) {
  mutate(AR = (x$Return - (y + (z * mkt.data$Return))))
}

firm.data.ar <- lapply(firm.data, ar_calc, y = alphas, z = betas)
firm.data.ar
```

The result should be a list including the two data frames X and Y which should both have a new column "AR". The values this column should be calculated with the "ar_calc" function.

Comment: Could you provide sample data with `dput(head(firm.data,12))`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the sample data in the post itself. There are only three rows for three dates in each data frame contained in firm.data.

Comment: What about alphas and betas? If you're using `mutate`, why not stick with canonical `dplyr` syntax ie `mutate(data,AR=......)`

Comment: Sorry, I have added the values for alphas, betas and the mkt.data set. I have tried that but it seems like the error is not due to the function ar_calc but more due to the lapply function I am using below.

Comment: Yes, maybe use `do.call` as it has more flexibility? Also maybe `reshape` your data for easier manipulation?

Comment: Thank you, could you maybe show me how to use ```do.call``` in this setting? Unfortunately I haven't used it yet since I am very new to R. 
Reshaping the data is sadly not possible at the moment due to several reasons, so I have to make do with it as it is.

Comment: Is `firm.data` a list?

Comment: Yes, right now it contains two data frames, one called X and one called Y (I published the data for X and Y in the post above). Once the code works I want to fill it with more than two data frames (which will all be similarly structured) to run the function for all data frames.